# Run "Android update project --path ." return invalided number of parameters

Tags: java, android, ant

I am using Windows 7 and I am new to Android development. I had no problem build android app with Ecliose, but I felt it would be very nice if I can build the android application with command lines. So,I have done some Google, and I found that I can use Ant to build my android app, so I have installed Ant and Added Android to my path.

When I run "Android update project --path ." command, I have got the following message, I am not sure if it is an error message or not.

The message was "invalid number of parameters the system cannon find the path specified. Updated local.properties"

Please give me some ideas on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Added Android to my path`

Please make sure you have added the `...\sdk\tools` to your path.Also you need to add the `apache-ant\bin` to your path.

So your environmental variables should look something like this

`Variable Name   PATH`

`Variable Values` `C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Users\HP\Eclipse Android Developer\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools`

Before updating a project also make sure that you have the latest version of `Android SDK Build Tools`.You can update your `Android SDK Build Tools` using the Android SDK manager.